# bearerbox in kannel running stops

Tags: kannel

i m trying to install kannel in centos i have downloaded the tar file and used following commands

./configure  ---prefix=/etc/kannel/
make
make install

then 
vi kannel.conf

```
group = core
admin-port = 1300
admin-password = fxxbar
box-allow-ip = "127.0.0.1"
admin-allow-ip = "127.0.0.1"

group = smsc
smsc = fake 
smsc-id = FAKE
port = 10000  
connect-allow-ip = 127.0.0.1

group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = 127.0.0.1
sendsms-port = 13013      
global-sender = 13013     
#log-file = "/tmp/smsbox.log"   
#log-level = 0    


#---------------------------------------------
# SEND-SMS USERS
#
# These users are used when Kannel smsbox sendsms interface is used to
# send PUSH sms messages, i.e. calling URL like
# http://kannel.machine:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=tester&password=foobar...

group = sendsms-user
username = tester
password = foobar
#user-allow-ip = ""


#---------------------------------------------
# SERVICES
#
# These are 'responses' to sms PULL messages, i.e. messages arriving from
# handsets. The response is based on message content. Only one sms-service is
# applied, using the first one to match.

group = sms-service
keyword = nop
text = "You asked nothing and I did it!"

# There should be always a 'default' service. This service is used when no
# other 'sms-service' is applied.

group = sms-service
keyword = default
text = "No service specified"
```

Then I used this command sbin/bearerbox kannel.conf and get the following result

```
2013-12-12 04:12:21 [27491] [0] INFO: SSL not supported, no SSL initialization d           one.
2013-12-12 04:12:21 [27491] [0] INFO: HTTP: Opening server at port 1300.
2013-12-12 04:12:21 [27491] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 1 (gwlib/fdset.c:poller)
2013-12-12 04:12:21 [27491] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 2 (gwlib/http.c:server_thr           ead)
2013-12-12 04:12:21 [27491] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 3 (gw/bb_http.c:httpadmin_           run)
2013-12-12 04:12:21 [27491] [0] DEBUG: starting smsbox connection module
2013-12-12 04:12:21 [27491] [0] ERROR: Missing smsbox-port variable, cannot star           t smsboxes
2013-12-12 04:12:21 [27491] [0] INFO: Set SMS resend frequency to 60 seconds.
2013-12-12 04:12:21 [27491] [0] INFO: SMS resend retry set to unlimited.
2013-12-12 04:12:21 [27491] [0] DEBUG: smsbox MO concatenated message handling e           nabled
2013-12-12 04:12:21 [27491] [0] INFO: DLR rerouting for smsc id <FAKE> disabled.
2013-12-12 04:12:21 [27491] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 4 (gw/smsc/smsc_fake.c:fak           e_listener)
2013-12-12 04:12:21 [27491] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 5 (gw/bb_smscconn.c:sms_ro           uter)
2013-12-12 04:12:21 [27491] [0] INFO: ----------------------------------------
2013-12-12 04:12:21 [27491] [0] INFO: Kannel bearerbox II version 1.4.3 starting
2013-12-12 04:12:21 [27491] [3] DEBUG: Thread 3 (gw/bb_http.c:httpadmin_run) map           s to pid 27491.
2013-12-12 04:12:21 [27491] [4] DEBUG: Thread 4 (gw/smsc/smsc_fake.c:fake_listen           er) maps to pid 27491.
2013-12-12 04:12:21 [27491] [5] DEBUG: Thread 5 (gw/bb_smscconn.c:sms_router) ma           ps to pid 27491.
2013-12-12 04:12:21 [27491] [0] INFO: MAIN: Start-up done, entering mainloop
2013-12-12 04:12:21 [27491] [0] DEBUG: smsc_fake: start called
2013-12-12 04:12:21 [27491] [2] DEBUG: Thread 2 (gwlib/http.c:server_thread) map           s to pid 27491.
2013-12-12 04:12:21 [27491] [1] DEBUG: Thread 1 (gwlib/fdset.c:poller) maps to p           id 27491.
```

The problem is it get stuck in the last line
"DEBUG: Thread 1 (gwlib/fdset.c:poller) maps to pid 27491."
and happening nothing after that what shld i do.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it is correct that nothing happened.
If you want sent sms:

- Start the SMSBox

  Open a new terminal and type the following command

  $ smsbox path_to_the_configuration_file
- You can use [FAKESMSC](http://www.kannel.org/download/kannel-userguide-snapshot/userguide.html#AEN5904) to sent fake sms: 
  Open a new terminal and type:

  $ test/fakesmsc

  it is not a real SMS center, if you want sent real sms configure the SMS Centre Group
  ([see User's Guide](http://www.kannel.org/download/kannel-userguide-snapshot/userguide.html#AEN1386))

Answer (score 0):

I think this configuration is wrong.You can use configuration file I used. [This](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VtH8OLg9fVB7qln5oW2oRaEJ73Sfb7-94M_Ngs4UfEo/edit) google document has many details. If you just want configuration file, just copy and paste the code.
For core group. Its like this

```
group = core
admin-port = 13000
smsbox-port = 13001
admin-password = abcd        #any admin pasword
status-password = ****        #your password for this username
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/bearerbox.log"
log-level = 0
box-deny-ip = "*.*.*.*"
box-allow-ip = "127.0.0.1"    #local host IP address
sms-resend-retry = 1
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This is my google document, and I am using it for configuring Kannel.
Thanks for suggesting it. I placed some example code from orginal kannel configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

> 2013-12-12 04:12:21 [27491] [0] ERROR: Missing smsbox-port variable,
>   cannot star

You have to specify the "smsbox-port"